# Cross-Platform 2D Graphics Renderer Library (Desktop & Mobile)

Tags: library, c++, c, drawing, programming

I am looking for an advanced (features) cross-platform drawing library. It needs to have **high performance**, but not really worrying about games as such. A big plus will be **SVG support,** writing is maybe not a requirement, but hopefully it could load one.

I must indicate that this library needs to be **embeddable,** as in I will be developing a apps for each platform in C# (Xamarin), and using P/Invoke to communicate with the underlying API.

It is also important that the **dev community be fairly active,** as the mobile platforms are moving quite fast... we can't have the graphics library falling behind on supported OS versions.

It can be C, C++ or whatever, but should **run on the basic platforms: Windows, Mac, iOS, Android and Windows Phone/Store/RT/Win8/Win10** (All lumped together because the Windows Runtime-compatibility is mostly the same).

I had a look at some, but they tend to be quite inactive and also only support desktop platforms. Some of the better ones include Skia and Cairo, but they both have limitations. Cairo is a bit inactive and doesn't run on Windows mobile. Skia is quite new, and doesn't support Windows platforms as well as the rest. Also it doesn't have SVG support.

I [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823145/cross-platform-2d-graphics-renderer-desktop-mobile).

Some links:

- [Cross-platform drawing library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200727/2533433)
- [Is there a good cross-platform C++ vector graphics library out there? [closed]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18795/is-there-a-good-cross-platform-c-vector-graphics-library-out-there)
- [Cross platform 2D Vector + Raster API + hardware accelerated - does this exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/546871/2533433)

Answer (score 1):

And... since this question, I have been working on SkiaSharp for some time and it is very good. The managed wrapper is what I work on, but the underlying C++ engine is all Google.

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp